# robust open source Kalman filter library in C++

Tags: programming, kalman

I would like to know if anyone has experience with a good open source kalman filter implementation in C++ that I could use. I require an implementation that supports computation of likelihood similar to KFAS in R.

Many thanks,
Pavy

Answer (score 7):

We use [KFilter](http://kalman.sourceforge.net/).

here is a link to their [documentation](http://kalman.sourceforge.net/doc/example.html#expage) page for you to peruse.

If you share a bit more about how you want to use the filter then it may help us.  However please note that suggest me a library questions are typically not on topic on any of the stack exchange sites

To update the answer to include the function the user wanted....

Here is the documentation to get [the error covariance matrix](http://kalman.sourceforge.net/doc/a00010.html#ac0985755b9fbeb6330aef0c34546a91)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does it provide a method to return the likelihood?

Comment: Found it. There is a method calculateP() that returns the prediction error matrix.

Comment: maybe a little late to the party but the error covariance matrix returned by KFilter is not suitable for the likelihood. In the documentation it says it's the posterior P matrix. You need the prior P matrix though.